# Why don't I get a response from my Sinatra web service using $.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, http-post

I'm sending JSON to a Sinatra web service via Ajax and I'm not getting any response.

This is the request:

```
$.post('http://url:port/service/task/create',JSON.stringify(sendData),function(data){
    alert('success!' + data);});
```

The Sinatra web service is:

```
post '/service/task/create' do

  puts 'create task'

  data = request.body.read
  jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
  puts 'received JSON: ' + jsonData.to_s

  data.to_json

end
```

I also tried:

```
json data
```

but nothing works.

I verified that the service receives the request and Firebug tells me that the request terminates with "200 OK" but the answer is empty.

Using a pure JavaScript Ajax-call I saw that the status is always `0` and I don't know why.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to post it as JSON? I've always found it makes things a lot more difficult. HTTP POST works perfectly. Aside from that, have you confirmed what the route receives? e.g. `warn "data = #{data.inspect}" etc (or use a debugger/pry)

Comment: The post method works perfectly fine. I'm receiving the JSON and can work with it. But I'm not able to send any response whether it's JSON or not and it the repsonse doesn't need to be JSON.

Comment: Have you tried it with a different, non-ajax/js client, like cURL? e.g. `curl -X POST --data 'querystring=here' http://example.org/service/task/create`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should try is adding a `content_type` to your handler, so Sinatra knows what to add to the HTTP response header:

```
post '/service/task/create' do

  content_type :json

  puts 'create task'

  data = request.body.read
  jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
  puts 'received JSON: ' + jsonData.to_s

  data.to_json

end
```

You can use `'application/json'` instead of `:json` if you want/need.

Also, you should be able to hit that URL from `curl` or using the command-line tool for [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). Send a bit of JSON and see what you get back.